# Android: How to on button click settext and setbackgroundresourse in another class and start it?

Tags: android, class, textview

I'm a newbie.
I need an app, where I can see some goods.
So, I have activity with many buttons. Each button is a preview for one of goods.
If I push that button with preview - it starts another class with another activity. There are big picture of goods (ImageView goodspic), name of goods (TextView goodsname), price of goods (TextView goodsprice) in this new activity.
But I think it's bad idea to make personal activity for each of goods :)
Question is: Is it possible to set on button click 2 strings for 2 different TextViews and 1 drawable resourse for ImageView in another class, and start it?

Comment: send your needed with Intent to second class and use that in second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other word you want to send two string and one int (drawable resourse) to another class.

so you can use Intent to do this work. in first class use following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("KEY1", firstString);
     intent.putExtra("KEY2" , secondString);
     intent.putExtra("KEY3" , yourInt) 
     startActivity(intent);
```

and in second class call this:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String key1 = b.getString("KEY1");
    String Key2 = b.getString("KEY2");
    int Key3 = b.getInt("KEY3");
```

/// and then

```
   TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
   TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
   ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);

   tv1.setText(Key1);
   tv2.setText(Key2);
   img.setImageResource(Key3);
```

Comment: I'm note sure I understand. This action send strings from one class to second, right? But how to add this strings to my TextView in second class?

Comment: I have xml for second class, and it have TextView1, TextView2 and ImageView. And I just need it change text in TextViews, and Drawable in ImageView, depends on what button I push.

Comment: I write this, but for some reason it's empty in place of TextViews, and Image is not changing too =( But thanx anyway, at least my app is not crashing now :D

Comment: check the value in `Key`. did you put this lines in `onCreate` method?
if you want to help more post your code

Comment: what is the String that want to pass to second class? value of TextView or just one String?

Comment: I will post my code later. I think it will be easier to explain.

Comment: I can't post my code again, but in works with some adjustments. I write int key1 = b.getInt("KEY1"), not String and getString